# Pass data to modal without angularUI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-directive

I am building an angular app and I am trying to pass data from my controller to a modal.

On my index page I have this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
...
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

<a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="callModal({{mydata.test}})">
click here
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

For my controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('JobListCtrl', ['$scope', '$element', '$http', '$log', function ($scope, $element, $http, $log,) {

    $scope.callModal = function(test){
        $scope.test = test;
    }

}]);
```

And my directive:

```
myApp.directive('myModal', ['$rootScope', '$log', '$http', function ($rootScope, $log, $http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',

    templateUrl: 'modal-tpl',

    replace: true,

    transclude: true,

    link: function (scope) {

    }
  };
}]);
```

And here is the template for my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-content ease">
    <section>
      {{test}}
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-overlay ease" data-dismiss="modal"></div>
</div>
```

How can I pass the value of mydata.test to the modal?
I have seen solution using angularUI, I know they work but I don't want to use their template for the modal.
Does anyone has an other solution?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

http://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/

angularJs have isolate scope with directive,

hopes it will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

Just a small comment:
When using an angular directive the double curly brackets for using angular models are extra.
So, instead of writing:
ng-click="callModal({{mydata.test}})
Use:
ng-click="callModal(mydata.test)